# How to set email alerts(Status of Job) to receive status for particular AWS Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-glue

Can anyone please help me to set up an email alert for particular AWS Glue Job using SNS and Cloud watch

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

1. Open cloudwatch
2. Create a new rule choose *glue* as service and *Glue Job Run Status* as Event Type.
3. Choose Any State to get notification related to start, running and stopped.
4. Add target and create a new SNS topic and add it as a target.

Now you will be able to receive the glue job notifications on your topic subscribers.